# If I use weight layout, then my Java file cannot find the view by id

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have an XML layout using weight layout like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Java file, I do like this, then my app crashes. If I don't use the weight layout, everything works fine.

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Comment: does `my app crashes` mean that `findViewById()` returns `null` and and it crashes when you try to call methods on the null object?

Comment: Hi Pragnani and Nevvek:  I cleaned the project and everything works.  :)  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything is fine. If you are using eclipse then Go to project -> clean and clean your project. then try to run or else restart your adb and eclipse. Then try to run.

Comment: I did some testing and the app works if I switch the webview and viewpage position.  like this.  Please see the answer I posted above.  I could not post here since the text is too long here.

Answer (score 1):

The app works if I switch the webview and viewpage position like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />
        <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set height for both of the controls as `match_parent` instead of `0dp`